# How to read tag ID from Zebra Printer

Tags: zebra-printers

We have a Zebra ZT410 RFID printer. In order to print a graphical drawing on the tag which contains the unique `TAG_ID`, we need to

1. read current tag's `TAG_ID` from printer
2. generate a visual drawing by using the `TAG_ID` value
3. print the generated drawing as usual

So, how can we read the current (the one will be printed on the next print command) tag's `TAG_ID`?

## Additional info

We successfully used the following ZPL code [described in the manual, on page 396](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) in order to make the printer read the `TAG_ID` and print it on the label:

```
^XA
^RB96,8,3,3,20,24,38^FS
^FO50,50^A0N,40^FN0^FS
^FN0^RFR,E^FS
^XZ
```

We have successfully executed this code 3-4 times, then tried something else according to our needs. Then we gave up, and tried to use the same code again and satisfy the results for now, but now we get 3 `void void void ... void void` labels as we executed exactly the same command.

Also, we tried to run the following ZPL code which is given by the manual, on page 402 in order to get the `TAG_ID`, but there is nothing returning back from the printer:

```
^XA
^FO20,120^A0N,60^FN0^FS
^RI0,,5^FS
^HV0,,Tag ID:^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this ZPL code to extract the UID and print in on the label:

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD10^JUS^LRN^CI0^RS8^XZ
^XA
^FO20,120^A0N,60^FN1^FS
^RFR,H,0,12,2^FN0^FS
^HV0,, ^FS
^BY4,3,110^FT288,250^BCN,,Y,N
^FN4^FS
^FN4^RFR,H,3,6,2^FS
^XZ
```

Using zebra 110Xi4

I encountered another problem, the UID barcode is printed correctly but the output to the screen is for the previews label.

Hope this helps,