# Reading RFID TAG ID from Zebra printer

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

I have Zebra ZT410 printer with RFID.I would like to use it to read and print labels but currently I'm having some problems with returnig the TAG_ID to my controller
The method to send ZPL string works fine and with the ZPL code from manual it can read current TAG_ID and print it on label.Here is the code to send the ZPL string

```
    public static bool Print(ZebraPrinter printer, string printstring)
    {
        bool sent = false;
        try
        {
            VerifyConnection(printer);
            printer.Connection.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(printstring));
            sent = true;
        }
        catch (ConnectionException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to write to printer: {e.Message}");
        }
        return sent;
    }
```

My question is if it's possible to read the TAG_ID on printer and return it to controller so i can store the TAG_ID.I tried using the ZPL code in manuall

```
^XA
^FO20,120^A0N,60^FN0^FS
^RI0,,5^FS
^HV0,,Tag ID:^FS
^XZ
```

But no matter what the returned data is always null
Here is the method to read the data:

```
public static bool Read(ZebraPrinter printer, string command)
    {
        bool sent = false;
        try
        {
            VerifyConnection(printer);
            var response = printer.Connection.SendAndWaitForResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command), 960, 650, "null");
            sent = true;
        }
        catch (ConnectionException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to read from printer: {e.Message}");
        }
        return sent;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like someone else has tried the exact same command as you. Did you check the answer to this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673315/how-to-read-tag-id-from-zebra-printer and did it work?

Comment: Yeah, i saw that but the ZPL code provided in answer printed blank label and didn't return any data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems that my printer doesn't support some of the newest ZPL commands and code provided in manual for ZPL wasn't working.
Here is the ZPL command that is returning the data

```
^XA
^RFR,H,0,8,2^FN1^FS^HV1,,8-byte Tag ID Data:^FS
^XZ
```